# How to collect some readable stack traces with perf?

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

I want to profile C++ program on Linux using random sampling that is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/72178):

> However, if you're in a hurry and you can manually interrupt your
>   program under the debugger while it's being subjectively slow, there's
>   a simple way to find performance problems.

The problem is that I can't use gdb debugger because I want to profile on production under heavy load and debugger is too intrusive and considerably slows down the program. However I can use `perf record` and `perf report` for finding bottlenecks without affecting program performance. Is there a way to collect a number of readable (gdb like) stack traces with perf instead of gdb?

Comment: IIRC, Chandler Carruth mentions compiling with frame pointers enabled (`-fno-omit-frame-pointer`) to let perf efficiently collect stack backtraces in his CppCon2015 talk about `perf`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk.  But I forget what perf options he then uses to tell `perf` it can use frame pointers and to get it to even collect parent callers.  It's a very good video, worth watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perf` does offer callstack recording with three different techniques

- By default is uses the frame pointer (`fp`). This is generally supported and performs well, but it doesn't work with certain optimizations. Compile your applications with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` etc. to make sure it works well.
- `dwarf` uses a dump of the sack for each sample for post-processing. That has a significant performance penalty
- Modern systems can use hardware-supported last branch record, `lbr`.

The stack is accessible in `perf` analysis tools such as `perf report` or `perf script`.

For more details check out `man perf-record`.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to add line numbers to stack traces in `perf script`? I tried `perf script -F +srcline`, but it seems they are not getting added. Is it `perf script` bug or am I doing it wrong?